# java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

i have to edit text fields and a text view where I have to do a calculation, and display it in the text view automatically using Text Watcher. But i'm facing an issue with empty string on edit text, when I enter a number in the edit text emulator crashes and the error is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

I converted Strings to double like below:

```
private void doCalculations() {
        String totalOutMekanik = edTotalOutMekanik.getText().toString();
        String totalInMekanik = edTotalInMekanik.getText().toString();

        // check if the string is empty
        if (!totalOutMekanik.isEmpty() && !totalInMekanik.isEmpty()) {
            double totOutMek = Double.parseDouble(totalOutMekanik);
            double totInMek = Double.parseDouble(totalInMekanik);
            double totInOutMek = totInMek - totOutMek;
            total_in_out_mekanik.setText(String.valueOf(totInOutMek));
        } else {

        }

    }
```

and I added an if conditions to check if the strings are null, and my Text Watcher

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                doCalculations();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };

        edTotalInMekanik.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        edTotalOutMekanik.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Edit:
My full stacktrance:

```
2020-01-09 11:17:50.354 8144-8144/al.sqmo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: al.sqmo, PID: 8144
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at al.sqmo.Activities.PutWeeklyDatasActivity.doCalculations(PutWeeklyDatasActivity.java:124)
        at al.sqmo.Activities.PutWeeklyDatasActivity.access$000(PutWeeklyDatasActivity.java:36)
        at al.sqmo.Activities.PutWeeklyDatasActivity$1.onTextChanged(PutWeeklyDatasActivity.java:79)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:9754)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:9851)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:12509)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1263)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:575)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:506)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:36)
        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:131)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7665)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7442)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2692)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:12450)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(NestedScrollView.java:592)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:428)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1820)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3360)
        at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:108)
        at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2533)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
2020-01-09 11:17:50.355 8144-8144/al.sqmo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4779)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2571)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2081)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2072)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2548)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Your `empty` check is not correct. Change your condition like `if (!totalOutMekanik.isEmpty() && !totalInMekanik.isEmpty())`

Comment: yeah its ok, I forgot to add when I asked question, now edited. But its not working.

Comment: Can you please add full stack trace of exception?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly do below changes, i.e. do trimming of string for space.

```
String totalOutMekanik = edTotalOutMekanik.getText().toString().trim();
String totalInMekanik = edTotalInMekanik.getText().toString().trim();
```

If you look [official document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) of the `{string}.isEmpty()`then you find just looks length of the string and tells wether it has value or not. It does not consider spaces. In your case I guess space was causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your are checking for empty for  following variable "totalOutMekanik". Try below code.

```
     private void doCalculations() {
    String totalOutMekanik  =edTotalOutMekanik.getText().toString().trim();
    String totalInMekanik = edTotalInMekanik.getText().toString().trim();

    // check if the string is empty
    if (!totalOutMekanik.isEmpty() && !totalInMekanik.isEmpty()) {
        double totOutMek = Double.parseDouble(totalOutMekanik);
        double totInMek = Double.parseDouble(totalInMekanik);
        double totInOutMek = totInMek - totOutMek;
        total_in_out_mekanik.setText(String.valueOf(totInOutMek));
    } else {

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you check empty is wrong. This is function of isEmpty in java:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
        // Android-changed: Get length from count field rather than value array (see above).
        // Empty string has {@code count == 0} with or without string compression enabled.
        // return value.length == 0;
        return count == 0;
    }
```

it's not check null. Fixed it by create a method to check:

```
 public static boolean isBlank(String myString) {
        if (myString == null) return false;
        return myString.trim().length() != 0;
    }
```

I sure it's work.